# Условия по переменной position в методе onBindViewHolder

Tags: kotlin, adapter

Всем привет, пишу тестовое задание на курсе, список фильмов из БД JSON. Язык КОТЛИН.
Проблема в том, что курс на Java, а я изучаю Котлин (на котлине такого курса не нашел), приходится постоянно адаптировать, в целом успешно.
Сейчас возникла проблема с методом onBindViewHolder в адаптере, он принимает переменную "position" которая указывает на позицию текущей карточки в RecyclerView.
Мне нужно реализовать метод определяющий, что мы долистали до конца списка (т.е достигли последней позиции в массиве).
Для этой задачи есть интерфейс с методом, который реализуется при достижении переменной "position" последнего значения в массиве.
НО, он сразу же вызывается при старте приложения! А потом уже работает как надо.

Проблема в том, что при запуске onBindViewHolder перебирает весь массив и соответственно переменная меняется от 0 до последнего значения в массиве (49 в моем случае) и конечно вызывается метод окончания списка, хотя сам список на экране находится в начальном положении.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти данную проблему? Или может по другому решить задачу?

Comment: onBindViewHolder никак не связан с текущей позицией в списке. Он вызывается при заполнении элементов данными. Может вызываться и несколько раз для одого элемента при переиспользовании UI элементов в длинных списках. Вам нужно повесить слушатель на скролл и дергать в нем этот метод https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Все верно, но onBindViewHolder всегда знает на какой позиции я нахожусь, и это можно было использовать, если бы не переборка всего списка в начале. За findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition спасибо, посмотрю что он делает, а пока нашел уже решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127734/detect-when-recyclerview-reaches-the-bottom-most-position-while-scrolling

Comment: Там ответов километр :) Включая и то что я предложил. Напишите в ответ что выбрали-то.